# On HTML, CSS and maybe Javascript or Jquery Apple iOS single click on a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

I have a website ([daccaa.com](https://daccaa.com/search)) and on my iPad or iPhone I have to click the Text Box twice rather than once to select it.

This is the code:

```
.box {
    width: 62%;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 9px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 9px;
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
}
.box:hover {
    width: 62%;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 9px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 9px;
    border: solid 1px #FFFB00;
    outline: none;
}
.box:focus {
    width: 62%;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 9px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    margin-top: 9px;
    border: solid 1px #FFD900;
    outline: none;
}
```

This is the CSS code for the textbox, I wondered if there is any javascript or jquery or even CSS that can be used to stop you from needing to click the textbox twice. I do not want to remove the hover and focus though.

Comment: This probably won't solve your problem, but since `.box:hover` and `.box:focus` have the exact same ruleset, you can simplify to one ruleset with `.box:hover, .box:focus { <rules> }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a media query to remove the *hover* when on mobile devices.   The reason for this is that on the iPhone (possibly other phones as well), when you click on an element that has hover, that first click will only fire the hover action.   The second will give focus to the element.

In your case, if you want to keep the hover for desktop visitors, you would want to use a media query to limit the hover to desktops (and not mobile devices).